# SwiftUI TextEditor Initial Content Size Is Wrong

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

*iOS 14.4 + Xcode 12.4*

I want to make a simple checklist in SwiftUI on iOS where the text for each item is a `TextEditor`.

[image]

First, I create the basic app structure and populate it with some demo content:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
  @State var alpha = "Alpha"
  @State var bravo = "Bravo is a really long one that should wrap to multiple lines."
  @State var charlie = "Charlie"
  
  init(){
    //Remove the default background of the TextEditor/UITextView
    UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ScrollView{
        VStack(spacing: 7){
          TaskView(text: $alpha)
          TaskView(text: $bravo)
          TaskView(text: $charlie)
        }
        .padding(20)
      }
      .background(Color.gray)
    }
  }
}
```

Then each `TaskView` represents a task (the white box) in the list:

```
struct TaskView:View{
  @Binding var text:String
  
  var body: some View{
    HStack(alignment:.top, spacing:8){
      Button(action: {
        print("Test")
      }){
        Circle()
          .strokeBorder(Color.gray,lineWidth: 1)
          .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.white))
          .frame(width:22, height: 22)
      }
      .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
      
      FieldView(name: $text)
       
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top:10, leading:10, bottom: 10, trailing: 30))
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(5)
  }
}
```

Then finally, each of the `TextEditor`s is in a `FieldView` like this:

```
struct FieldView: View{
  @Binding var name: String
  var body: some View{
    ZStack{
      Text(name)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -7, leading: -3, bottom: -5, trailing: -3))
        .opacity(0)
      TextEditor(text: $name)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -7, leading: -3, bottom: -5, trailing: -3))
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot above, the initial height of the `TextEditor` doesn't automatically size to fit the text. But as soon as I type in it, it resizes appropriately. Here's a video that shows that:

[image]

How can I get the view to have the correct initial height? Before I type in it, the `TextEditor`  scrolls vertically so it seems to have the wrong intrinsic content size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: views are left semi-transparent with borders so you can see/debug what's going on.*

```
struct FieldView: View{
    @Binding var name: String
    @State private var textEditorHeight : CGFloat = 100
    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text(name)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)

                })
                //.opacity(0)
                .border(Color.pink)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                
            TextEditor(text: $name)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -7, leading: -3, bottom: -5, trailing: -7))
                .frame(height: textEditorHeight + 12)
                .border(Color.green)
                .opacity(0.4)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { textEditorHeight = $0 }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
        print("Reporting height: \(value)")
    }
}
```

First, I used a `PreferenceKey` to pass the height from the "invisible" text view back up the view hierarchy. Then, I set the height of the `TextEditor` frame with that value.

Note that the view is now aligned to `topLeading` -- in your initial example, the invisible text was center aligned.

One thing I'm not crazy about is the use of the edge insets -- these feel like magic numbers (well, they are...) and I'd rather have a solution without them that still kept the `Text` and `TextEditor` completely aligned. But, this works for now.

#### Update, using UIViewRepresentable with UITextView

This seems to work and avoid the scrolling problems:

```
struct TaskView:View{
    @Binding var text:String
    @State private var textHeight : CGFloat = 40
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack(alignment:.top, spacing:8){
            Button(action: {
                print("Test")
            }){
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.gray,lineWidth: 1)
                    .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.white))
                    .frame(width:22, height: 22)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            FieldView(text: $text, heightToTransmit: $textHeight)
                .frame(height: textHeight)
                .border(Color.red)
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top:10, leading:10, bottom: 10, trailing: 30))
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}

struct FieldView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text : String
    @Binding var heightToTransmit: CGFloat
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.backgroundColor = .yellow // visual debugging
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false   // causes expanding height
        context.coordinator.textView = textView
        textView.text = text
        view.addSubview(textView)

        // Auto Layout
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.heightBinding = $heightToTransmit
        context.coordinator.textBinding = $text
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            context.coordinator.runSizing()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var textBinding : Binding<String>?
        var heightBinding : Binding<CGFloat>?
        var textView : UITextView?
        
        func runSizing() {
            guard let textView = textView else { return }
            textView.sizeToFit()
            self.textBinding?.wrappedValue = textView.text
            self.heightBinding?.wrappedValue = textView.frame.size.height
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            runSizing()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very slick solution, thank you. The only remaining issue I see is that the `TextEditor` still scrolls if you swipe it up or down. Here's a GIF from the Simulator that shows what I mean: https://cln.sh/SL7xMv Is that an unavoidable side effect of using a `TextEditor`?

Comment: I would think so, since TextEditor is inherently a scroll view, but I could be wrong. If it were UIKit, you could probably disable scrolling unless it was the current first responder.

Comment: I've tried setting `textView.isScrollEnabled = false` on a `UITextView` (via `UIViewRepresentable`) but it didn't behave like it does in a UIKit app. I don't know how to make it behave as if its edges have auto layout constraints pinned to its parent.

Comment: This is really cool, thank you! I tried the `UIViewRepresentable` and it works great with one catch. If you set an initial text value for one of the tasks that's really long (like 5 lines worth of text) then the initial height of the task is still only the default `textHeight: 40`. But as soon as I type in the field, the height updates to be correct. I tried calling `sizeToFit` on the `textView` in `updateUIView` but it didn't help. Are you seeing that same issue or does it work for you?

Comment: Just updated it to account for that scenario. Try again and let me know.

Comment: Ah, fantastic! I was trying to do something like that but inside `updateUIView` I kept getting a `0` for `context.coordinator.textView?.frame.size.height`. This situation shows where SwiftUI is a little weak--this scenario was much easier in UIKit.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: After some trial and error and a red-hot CPU, I discovered that calling `runSizing()` inside `updateUIView()` causes an infinite loop. I guess it triggers a view change and makes it call itself again. I tried setting the initial size in `makeUIView()` but it doesn't seem to have the right height yet. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd probably be looking at ways to check whether it *really needs* to resize -- eg, has the text changed. So, maybe storing an older version of the state and then comparing the values, only calling runSizing if it needs it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `guard self.textBinding?.wrappedValue != textView.text else{ return }` inside `runSizing()` but the values are always equal. It seems `runSizing` needs to get called at least once before the initial height can be calculated. I'll keep digging. Thanks!